# How to show paging at the bottom of the page ??

Tags: php, datagrid

I have created a datagrid with php and I have calculated count of records of table and datagrid show in per page 10 record.

My problem is paging to show at the bottom of datagrid. If count of records increases then number of pages in bottom div not displayed.

If my records will 1000 and will display 10 records per page,then counts of page will 100.

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++) { ?>
<li><a><?php print("$i"); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

This top code is displayed :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 ... 100

and I want if user click on page of 12 , pages 1 to 9 will not display :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

You have to set $numberItems which is the total number of items, $firstElementDisplayed the index of the current element displayed, $itemsPerPage the number of items displayed per page and $showeachside the number of page you want to display either side of selected page

```
<?php

    $numberItems = 20; // Number of items;
    $firstElementDisplayed = 3; // Current start element position

    $itemsPerPage = 2; // Number of items showed per page
    $showeachside = 3; //  Number of page displayed either side of selected page

    if(empty($firstElementDisplayed))$firstElementDisplayed=0;  // Current start element position

    $page_count = ceil($numberItems / $itemsPerPage); // Number of pages
    $currentPage = ceil($firstElementDisplayed / $itemsPerPage); // Current page
?>
<?php
if(($firstElementDisplayed-$itemsPerPage) >= 0) //We are not on the first page => << is displayed
{
?>
<a href="#urlFirstPage"><<</a> 
<?php
}
?>
<?php 
$eitherside = ($showeachside * $itemsPerPage);
if($firstElementDisplayed+1 > $eitherside) echo " .... ";
$page=1;
for($y=0;$y<$numberItems;$y+=$itemsPerPage)
{
    $class=($y==$firstElementDisplayed)?"pageselected":"";
    if(($y > ($firstElementDisplayed - $eitherside)) && ($y < ($firstElementDisplayed + $eitherside)))
    {
        ?>
        <a class="<?php print($class);?>" href="#urlPage"><?php print($page);?></a>
        <?php
    }
    $page++;
}
if(($firstElementDisplayed+$eitherside)<$numberItems)print (" .... ");
?>
<?php 
if($firstElementDisplayed+$itemsPerPage<$numberItems) //We are not on the last page => >> is displayed
{
?>
<a href="#urlLastPage">>></a> 
<?php
}
?>
Page <?php print($currentPage);?> of <?php print($page_count);?>
```